# Error: Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
Epoch 1/20
 188/3000 [>.............................] - ETA: 44:48 - loss: 0.0742 - accuracy: 0.9750WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting traini
ng. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 60020 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 3000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
3000/3000 [==============================] - 347s 115ms/step - loss: 0.0742 - accuracy: 0.9750 - val_loss: 0.0909 - val_accuracy: 0.9672
```

He estado leyendo las consultas de otras personas pero no me queda clara la solución

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
Total de imágenes en cada carpeta = 3000
Tamaño de cada imagen = 38x46
Número de objetos diferentes = 2
```

En el códgio tengo:

```
epocas=20
h, w = 38, 46
batch_size = 32
step = 3000
validation_s = 600
filtConv1 = 32
filtConv2 = 64
s_filtro1 = (3, 3)
s_filtro2 = (2, 2)
s_pool = (2, 2)
class = 2
lr = 0.0004
...
cnn.fit_generator(
    imag_train,
    steps_per_epoch=step,
    epochs=epocas,
    validation_data=imag_vali,
    validation_steps=validation_s)
```

Alguien sabe si los datos están bien puestos?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

A mi me salía el mismo error y lo solucioné bajando los pasos y las validaciones.

Si tienes 3000 fotos en la carpeta de entrenamiento, las procesas de 32 en 32 (batch size) y lo haces 3000 veces (step) entonces te repites y por eso te da error. 3000/32 = 93,75 prueba a poner los steps en 92.

Lo mismo tienes que hacer con las validaciones